# Modal window overlay div is not covering the whole page, when the page is scrolled down, in angular js

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, scrollview, overlay

I have a modal window overlay section css as below:

```
.ng-modal-overlay {  position:absolute;  z-index:9999;  top:0;  left:0; width:100%;  height:100%;  background-color:#000000;  opacity: 0.9;}
```

But it is not covering the whole page when the page is scrolled down. This is used in modal custom directive in angular js.

screenshot:

[image]

Edit 1:

screenshot after making position: relative

[image]

Edit 2: Code for HTML template:

```
$templateCache.put('views/modal-dialog.html',
"<div class=\"ng-modal\" ng-show=\"show\">\n" +
"   <div class=\"ng-modal-overlay\" ng-click = \"modal.hideModal()\"></div>\n" +
"       <div class=\"ng-modal-dialog\" ng-style=\"dialogStyle\">\n" +
"           <div class=\"ng-modal-close\" ng-click = \"modal.hideModal()\">X</div>\n" +
"               <div class=\"ng-modal-dialog-content\" >\n" +
"               Segmentations of {{product.productName.value}}\n" +
"               <br>\n" +
"                   <label for=\"custBeliefSys\"> Cust. Belief Sys </label><br>" +
"                   <div >\n" +
"                       <select name = \"custBeliefSys\" multiple style=\"width: 100%\" ng-options=\"e as e.Id for e in modal.custBeliefSys track by e.Id\" ng-model=\"modal.selectedCustBeliefSys\">\n" +        
"                       </select>\n" +
"                   </div>\n" +
"               <br>\n" +
"                   <label for=\"hcpSegment\"> HCP Segment </label><br>" +
"                   <div >\n" +
"                       <select name = \"hcpSegment\" multiple style=\"width: 100%\" ng-options=\"e as e.Id for e in modal.hcpSegment track by e.Id\" ng-model=\"modal.selectedHcpSegment\">\n" +        
"                       </select>\n" +
"                   </div>\n" +
"       </div>\n" +
"       </div>\n" +
"</div>\n" 
);
```

```css
Code for CSS:

    .ng-modal-overlay {
  /* A dark translucent div that covers the whole screen */
  position:relative;
  z-index:9999;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color:#000000;
  opacity: 0.9;
}
.ng-modal-dialog {
  /* A centered div above the overlay with a box shadow. */
  z-index:10000;
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%; /* Default */

  /* Center the dialog */
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 80px #000;
}
.ng-modal-dialog-content {
  padding:10px;
  text-align: left;
}
.ng-modal-close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px;
  right: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 120%;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: 'arial', 'sans-serif';
}
.modal-heading {
  background: #eaeaea;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

Comment: position:relative; to the body

Comment: You could also try using `bottom: 0` instead of `height: 100%` . But it's also dependent on how hight the parent is and if the parent has `position: relative` set

Comment: @Temani Afif, I've tried the solution but then the blur background is showing as the screenshots in the edited answer. please see.

Comment: @Ramiz, I've tried your solution, but it is remaining same as before.

Comment: share some code then

Comment: Try with `position: fixed` rather than `absolute`

Comment: @Alexis thanks, it worked with  position: fixed, thanks everyone for your help

Comment: @Dmitry thanks, it worked with  position: fixed